# Changing feature name inside Cucumber hooks

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I created tags for enabling and disabling [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) in my specifications

Example:

```
@with_toggle_name
  Scenario: Example scenario with toggle toggle_name
    Given I....

@without_toggle_name
  Scenario: Example scenario without toggle toggle_name
    Given I....
```

The hooks are something like this:

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  toggles_on  = scenario.source_tag_names.map { |t| Regexp.last_match[1].to_sym if t =~ /^@with_(.*)/ }.compact

  run_with_toggles(*toggles_on) do
    block.call
  end
end

Around do |scenario, block|
  toggles_off = scenario.source_tag_names.map { |t| Regexp.last_match[1].to_sym if t =~ /^@without_(.*)/ }.compact

  run_without_toggles(*toggles_off) do
    block.call
  end
end
```

I was trying to execute the same feature first with and then without the feature toggles.

Something like this:

```
@with_and_without_toggle_name
  Scenario: Example scenario with toggle toggle_name
    Given I....
```

And with the hooks like this:

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  toggles  = scenario.source_tag_names.map { |t| Regexp.last_match[1].to_sym if t =~ /^@with_and_without_(.*)/ }.compact

  original_scenario_name = scenario.name

  scenario.name = original_scenario.name + " with toggles " + toggles.join(", ")
  run_with_toggles(*toggles) do
    block.call
  end

  scenario.name = original_scenario.name + " without toggles " + toggles.join(", ")
  run_without_toggles(*toggles) do
    block.call
  end
end
```

This way I would have the same feature executed two times with different names, but this code doesn't work because there is no accessor to change the name of the scenario.

Does somebody know how to do what I want?